# How to ignore already included objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wrote the following code:

```
let self = this;
self.rows = [];
self.data.payload.forEach(function (item, index) {
    if (!(self.rows.includes(item))) {
        self.rows.push(item);
    }
});
```

And `includes` always return false. Each item is of format:

```
{
'user': 'ben',
'age':  '23'
}
```

It could be more fields than just those two, the important thing is it's an object. The result is that I have duplicates in the `self.rows`. So I don't want to include duplicates. How can I iterate over those items and push them into `rows` only if this object is not already included?  The idea of using `includes` was taken from a previous topic on this subject.

**EDIT**: I used loadsh as was suggested in the commants and got:

```
self.data.payload.forEach(function (item, index) {
    var seen = false;
    for (var row_index = 0; row_index < self.rows.length; ++row_index) {
        if (isEqual(self.rows[row_index],item)) {
            seen = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!seen) {
        self.rows.push(item);
    }
});
```

It works! But I iterate over 20000 items in the `self.data` so it gets quite heavy and takes quite time. Is there a smarter way to achieve it?

Comment: lodash library has isEqual() method which enables you to compare objects. Maybe you can check existing objects in your array before pushing the new one

Comment: @ozgur so I'll need to add another loop inside on rows for that right?

Comment: Yes you need a loop here that will compare existing objects in the array: if (!(self.rows.includes(item)))

Comment: How do you distinguish `ben 23` from another user that is named "ben" with age "23"?

Comment: @RickardElimää The fields are just an example so it will be easier to understand. The rows just should not contain duplicates, does not matter what that is in.

Comment: the 'includes' function of js always returns the position of element if its present in the array else returns -1 . So your if condition should be....if (self.rows.includes(item) !== -1)

Answer (score 1):

so as I see the reason you get duplicates in your array is because .includes() method of Array uses SameValueZero algorithm to compare values.
Follow this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) you will find that object cannot be compared in the way you try to do it (that is why checking *self.rows.includes(item)* will always return false).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid uses of extra loops, I would use an object to store properties. Do a quick lookup in said object, and either 1) add a new property if none exist for the user, or 2) don't push if the property already exists.

```js
let self = this;
self.rows = [];

/* Only added to show the functionality */
class User {
  constructor(user, age) {
    this.user = user;
    this.age = age;
  }  
}

self.data = [];
self.data.payload = [new User('ben', 23), new User('ben', 23), new User('alice', 35), new User('alice', 32)];

/* The important declaration here */
var rowsObj = {};
var key = "";        // to avoid creating variables in the loop

self.data.payload.forEach(function (item) {
    key = item.user + item.age;

    if (!rowsObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        self.rows.push(item);
        rowsObj[key] = 1;
    }
});

console.log(self.rows);
```